# nmcli problem after the installation of network-manager

Tags: nmcli

I installed `network-manager`.

But the `nmcli` does not work with the error below.

```
ens33: unmanaged
    ...
lo: unmanaged
    ...
```

I started `bind9` before this by `systemctl restart bind9`.
I want a related connection to be shown by `nmcli connection show`

Comment: Please edit your question to show the results of the terminal commands: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and also: `cat /etc/network/interfaces` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: network:ethernets:ens33:dhcp4:true:version: 2. And /etc/network/interfaces does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see by the netplan .yaml file, your ethernet connection is currently being managed directly by netplan. There is nothing inherently wrong with this. I assume that the ethernet works properly as is. However, if you wish for Network Manager to manage the ethernet connection, please amend the .yaml file:

```
sudo rm /etc/netplan/*.yaml
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

Write a new file:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Indentation and spacing are crucial; proofread twice. Save (Ctrl+o) and close (Ctrl+x) the text editor. Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
sudo service network-manager restart
```

You should be all set.